# How to use a combobox in ms Access to display the value of field in table and at the same time present the users with a list of options to edit?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an unbound form where my controls (among which there are some comboxes) are filled with data in a DAO.Recordset rst (opened with a SELECT SQL statement):

```
me.Controls("mycontrol").Value = rst.Fields("somefield")
```

The combobox displays the correct value ('YES' or 'NO') stored in the table. How can I make the combobox display these two options to the user if he wants to change the value? And how to I get the value the user picked (in VBA)?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I think I did it!

```
mycontrol.RowSourceType = "Value List"
mycontrol.RowSource = "YES;NO"
```